# Is there a logical methodology to classify things?

Tags: logic, knowledge-representation

I wonder if there is any established logical methodology to classify things?

Update:

My concern is to have a good method that lets me classify information in any context. I am actually a programmer. Every day, I learn new stuff. I try to store everything I learned in an organized manner. I use an outliner note taking tool called as Keynote from Tranglos software. It allows me to organize the information in a hierarchical structure. But building a good hierarchical structure of knowledge is not easy. Usually, I don't build the structure according to some all encompassing logic. Instead, I try to organize the structure as I learn new knowledge.

I wonder if there is any established method to classify knowledge in an encompassing way such that new knowledge fits into the existing structure in an easy way. Having a good clasiffication of knowledge lets one to understand a complex topic much easier and to solve problems more effectively.

Comment: Can you tell us a little bit more about your concern here?

Comment: You might be interested in the discipline of "information retrieval" (a subdomain of computer science), or indeed in library science.

Comment: @Mert - Being a programmer like yourself, I know exactly what you mean, particularly when it comes to software architecture / program flow. *Ad hoc* is the way to go, unless you're up for a really big project!

Comment: Not philosophical, but what about the classical single inheritance OOP hierarchy (tree) where the root is the most general thing (e.g. *object*) and descendants are more specific but *a kind of* their ancestors?  Closer to the root things are more general and farther from the root things are more specific.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [Dewey Decimal Classification System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dewey_Decimal_Classification)

Answer (score 2):

When you ask, "Is there a logical methodology to classify things?" the answer is a resounding ***yes***, there are many classification systems developed throughout history that attempted to follow a common, and logical, methodology. However, when you ask if there is "any ***established*** logical methodology", the answer is much less clear. Most of these classification systems are specific to their usage and don't cover every conceivable category in existence; I doubt you would find many that attempt to cover the entire extent of human knowledge in any great detail. Most philosophers who speak about things like this speak on a much higher level than you are looking for (see [some examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_being#History)).

Your best bet, honestly, is to create your own that is specific to your needs, using other examples that are similar in order to help you. You can be as simple or complex as you require. The general field your question falls under is **metaphysics** ([[SEP]](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/metaphysics/)[[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphysics)), specifically ***[ontology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology)***. This is a MASSIVE field in philosophy with an incredible amount of literature, and if you want to build a super-hardcore organizational structure you'll need to dig in a little and decide on what you think regarding the [categories of being](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_being), what [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_%28philosophy%29) exist in the universe, what constitutes the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_%28philosophy%29) of a thing (what are the [essential properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essence), if any), the [problem of universals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_universals), and a whole lot more.

You might, I reckon, find it easier to start with [DDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dewey_Decimal_Classification) and [LCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_of_Congress_Classification) and make your own changes. In my opinion, those systems used by libraries might be a good start but need serious work. Who bunches philosophy with psychology? "History, geography & biography"??? Makes me cringe.